# Jenkins Declarative pipeline for multi-branch pipleline

Tags: php, groovy

I am working on setting up automated build and deploy jobs in jenkins for a php based project. I would like some feedback on my Jenkinsfile. Specifically regarding the parallelization, the (in my opinion) huge usage of `sh` and the best practices regarding the site configuration (would a bunch of included files be better?).

```
#!groovy
//TODO: SSH-steps? https://jenkins.io/blog/2019/02/06/ssh-steps-for-jenkins-pipeline/
//TODO: move some stuff to shared library for ease of use https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/
node{
     switch (env.BRANCH_NAME) {
        case "Production":
            echo "Production is not yet implemented"
            //DEPLOY_DIR          = ""

            //SITE_TITLE          = ""
            //SITE_NAME           = ""
            //SITE_FQDN           = ""
            //DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL  = ""
            //SESSION_NAME        = ""

            //MYSQL_HOSTNAME      = ""
            //MYSQL_DB_NAME       = ""
            //MYSQL_USERNAME      = ""
            //MYSQL_PASSWORD      = ""

            //SSH_SERVER_NAME     = ""
            //SSH_USERNAME        = ""

            break
        case "Development":
        case "development":
            DEPLOY_DIR          = "/var/www/somesite_dev"

            SITE_TITLE          = "blablabla"
            SITE_NAME           = "blablabla.dev.mydomain.dk"
            SITE_FQDN           = "blablabla.dev.mydomain.dk"
            DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL  = "dev@mydaomain.dk"
            SESSION_NAME        = "TestSession"

            MYSQL_HOSTNAME      = "localhost"
            MYSQL_DB_NAME       = "somedb"
            MYSQL_USERNAME      = "uname"
            MYSQL_PASSWORD      = "p@sswørd" //TODO Move to Jenkins credential management

            SSH_SERVER_NAME     = "ssh.mydomain.dk"
            SSH_USERNAME        = "jenkins"
            break
        case "Test":
            DEPLOY_DIR          = "/var/www/somesite_test"

            SITE_TITLE          = "blablabla"
            SITE_NAME           = "blablabla.test.mydomain.dk"
            SITE_FQDN           = "blablabla.test.mydomain.dk"
            DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL  = "test@mydaomain.dk"
            SESSION_NAME        = "DevSession"

            MYSQL_HOSTNAME      = "localhost"
            MYSQL_DB_NAME       = "somedb"
            MYSQL_USERNAME      = "uname"
            MYSQL_PASSWORD      = "p@sswørd" //TODO Move to Jenkins credential management

            SSH_SERVER_NAME     = "ssh.mydomain.dk"
            SSH_USERNAME        = "jenkins"
            break
        default:
            echo "$BRANCH_NAME Does not yet have a configuration."
            break
    }   
}
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        SOURCE_DIR="${WORKSPACE}/src"
        BACKUP_FNAME="/tmp/BACKUP-${SITE_NAME}-${(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HHmm")).format((new Date()))}.tar.gz"
    }
    triggers {
        bitbucketPush()
        pollSCM('') // empty cron expression string
    }

    stages {
        stage ('Staging'){
            environment {
                TEMPLATE_FILE="globals.template.inc.php"
                CONFIG_FILE="globals.inc.php"
            }
            steps {
                echo "Cleanup build artifacts"
                //remove build folder
                sh 'rm -R -f ${WORKSPACE}/build'
                echo "Prepare for build"
                //re-create folders
                sh 'mkdir ${WORKSPACE}/build ${WORKSPACE}/build/api ${WORKSPACE}/build/coverage ${WORKSPACE}/build/logs ${WORKSPACE}/build/pdepend ${WORKSPACE}/build/phpdox'
                echo "Running composer"
                sh "composer install -o -d ${SOURCE_DIR}"
                echo "Building config file ${SOURCE_DIR}/${CONFIG_FILE}"
                script {
                    def inptext = readFile file: "${SOURCE_DIR}/${TEMPLATE_FILE}" 
                    //save deploydate
                    def deployDate = (new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")).format((new Date()))                    
                    inptext = inptext.replaceAll(~/¤SITE_TITLE¤/, "${SITE_TITLE}")
                    inptext = inptext.replaceAll(~/¤SITE_NAME¤/, "${SITE_NAME}")
                    inptext = inptext.replaceAll(~/¤SITE_FQDN¤/, "${SITE_FQDN}")
                    inptext = inptext.replaceAll(~/¤DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL¤/, "${DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL}")
                    inptext = inptext.replaceAll(~/¤SESSION_NAME¤/, "${SESSION_NAME}")
                    inptext = inptext.replaceAll(~/¤MYSQL_HOSTNAME¤/, "${MYSQL_HOSTNAME}")
                    inptext = inptext.replaceAll(~/¤MYSQL_DB_NAME¤/, "${MYSQL_DB_NAME}")
                    inptext = inptext.replaceAll(~/¤MYSQL_USERNAME¤/, "${MYSQL_USERNAME}")
                    inptext = inptext.replaceAll(~/¤MYSQL_PASSWORD¤/, "${MYSQL_PASSWORD}")
                    inptext = inptext.replaceAll(~/¤DEPLOY_DATE¤/, "${deployDate}")
                    inptext = inptext.replaceAll(~/¤GIT_BRANCH¤/, "${env.GIT_BRANCH}")
                    inptext = inptext.replaceAll(~/¤GIT_COMMIT¤/, "${env.GIT_COMMIT}")
                    //inptext = inptext.replaceAll(~/¤GIT_TAG¤/, "${sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git -C . describe --tags").trim()}")
                    writeFile file: "${SOURCE_DIR}/${CONFIG_FILE}", text: inptext
                }
            }
        }
        stage ('Testing, Static Analysis & documenting'){
            parallel {
                stage ("Count LOC"){
                    steps {
                        //    echo "Running Lint"
                        //    sh "find . -path ./src/vendor -prune -o -type f -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -P4 php -l -n | (! grep -v \"No syntax errors detected\" )"
                        echo "Running phploc"
                        sh "./src/vendor/phploc/phploc/phploc --exclude=./src/vendor --no-interaction --quiet --log-csv=./build/logs/loc.csv src tests"

                        echo "Running sloc"
                        sh "sloccount --duplicates --wide --details . > ./build/logs/sloccount.sc  2>/dev/null"
                    }
                }
                stage ("Copy-Paste Detection"){
                    steps{
                        echo "Running copy-paste detection"
                        sh "./src/vendor/sebastian/phpcpd/phpcpd --fuzzy . --exclude src/vendor --log-pmd ./build/logs/phpcpd.xml || true"
                    }
                }
                stage ("Mess Detection"){
                    steps{
                        echo "Running mess detection on code"
                        sh "./src/vendor/phpmd/phpmd/src/bin/phpmd src xml phpmd_ruleset.xml --reportfile ./build/logs/phpmd_code.xml --exclude vendor,build --ignore-violations-on-exit --suffixes php"
                        //echo "Running mess detection on tests"
                        //sh "./src/vendor/phpmd/phpmd/src/bin/phpmd tests xml codesize,cleancode,unusedcode,naming --reportfile ./build/logs/phpmd_tests.xml --suffixes php"
                    }
                }
                stage ("Testing"){
                    steps{
                        echo "Running PHPUnit w/o code coverage"
                        sh "./src/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --configuration phpunit-quick.xml" 
                    }
                }
                //echo "Running PHP Codesniffer"
                //sh "phpcs --report=checkstyle --report-file=./build/logs/checkstyle.xml --standard=PSR2 --extensions=php --ignore=autoload.php ./src ./tests"

                //TODO: phpdox 

                // TODO: set up reporting
                // https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Plot+Plugin
                // https://stackoverflow.com/a/48001251/1725871
            }
        }
        stage ("Deploy") {
            environment {
                SSH_TUNNEL_PORT=3309
            }
            parallel {
                stage ("Deploy code") {
                    agent any
                    steps {
                        echo "Deploying via SSH  on ${SSH_SERVER_NAME}:${DEPLOY_DIR}"
                        //TODO: rename backup file
                        sh "ssh ${SSH_USERNAME}@${SSH_SERVER_NAME} tar -cvpzf ${BACKUP_FNAME} ${DEPLOY_DIR}/* "
                        sh "ssh ${SSH_USERNAME}@${SSH_SERVER_NAME} rm -R -f ${DEPLOY_DIR}/*"
                        sh "scp -rpC ${SOURCE_DIR}/* ${SSH_USERNAME}@${SSH_SERVER_NAME}:${DEPLOY_DIR}"
                        //TODO: delete backup on success
                    }
                }
                stage ("Deploy DB changes") {
                    agent any //liquibase
                    steps {
                        echo "Create SSH tunnel"
                        sh "ssh -M -S deploy-control-socket -fnNT -L ${SSH_TUNNEL_PORT}:localhost:3306 ${SSH_USERNAME}@${SSH_SERVER_NAME}"

                        echo "Check tunnel"
                        sh "ssh -S deploy-control-socket -O check ${SSH_USERNAME}@${SSH_SERVER_NAME}"

                        echo "Sync liquibase"
                        sh "liquibase --driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver --changeLogFile=${WORKSPACE}/resources/database/db.changelog-1.1.xml --url=\"jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:${SSH_TUNNEL_PORT}/${MYSQL_DB_NAME}?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC\" --username=${MYSQL_USERNAME} --password=${MYSQL_PASSWORD} update"

                        echo "Close SSH tunnel to ${SSH_SERVER_NAME}"
                        sh "ssh -S deploy-control-socket -O exit ${SSH_USERNAME}@${SSH_SERVER_NAME}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            //archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'build/libs/**/*.jar', fingerprint: true
            junit "build/logs/junit.xml"

            sloccountPublish encoding: '', pattern: ''
            // warnings-ng https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-ng-plugin/blob/master/doc/Documentation.md
            recordIssues enabledForFailure: true, tool: cpd(pattern: 'build/logs/phpcpd.xml')
            recordIssues enabledForFailure: true, tool: pmdParser(pattern: 'build/logs/phpmd_code.xml')
        }
        //https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/post/
        success {
            echo 'Successful build. Well done'
        }
        unstable {
            echo 'Unstable Build. Check test cases'
        }
        failure {
            echo 'I failed :('
        }
        changed {
            echo 'Things were different before...'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know enough about these technologies to help you, but I think people would receive your question better if you could be a little more specific, considering the amount of code there is to go through.

Answer (score 2):

I have found an inherent flaw in the backup and copy part. Namely

```
sh "ssh ${SSH_USERNAME}@${SSH_SERVER_NAME} tar -cvpzf ${BACKUP_FNAME} ${DEPLOY_DIR}/*"
sh "ssh ${SSH_USERNAME}@${SSH_SERVER_NAME} rm -R -f ${DEPLOY_DIR}/*"
```

Which both exand the asterisk on the local mashine, and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22222838/shell-script-calling-ssh-how-to-interpret-wildcard-on-remote-server

The solution for tar is simple:

```
sh "ssh ${SSH_USERNAME}@${SSH_SERVER_NAME} tar -cvpzf ${BACKUP_FNAME} ${DEPLOY_DIR}"
```

The solution for rm is more difficult.
I have considered the [ssh steps plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SSH+Steps+Plugin), but I would like some more surety of whether it would work before I try it...

Right now I am looking into `rsync` with the `--DELETE` flag set.